# SQL Injection attempt, how does it work

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I was looking at the logs and found a sql injection. Looks like it is used alot but I don't really understand how it works. I attempted to submit it through the form they submitted it through but nothing happens.

The injection string is:

```
(select(0)from(select(sleep(0)))v)/*''+(select(0)from(select(sleep(0)))v)+''"+(select(0)from(select(sleep(0)))v)+"*/
```

Can't figure out how they injected it. Didn't affect the server from what I can tell. They didn't get any data. But I still want to know how they made it work.

Comment: Not sure what they're doing, but from what logs did you get this? Maybe they just used this a failed attempt to SQL injection. If you can provide the code executing this, we can look and see if it's vulnerable or not.

Comment: Not sure but this seems relevant: http://www.sqlinjection.net/time-based/

Comment: What database are you using?MySql?

Comment: I assume the logged string is after passing through whatever sanitization you have in place (if any)? We can't really tell you how it went through without knowing how you sanitize your input.

Comment: No idea how it works since you give no hint about your application

Comment: FYI: I also found that someone is trying to get my server to run queries like this, select(sleep(15)... In my case, they make HTML requests, setting the query string as the value of the real CSRF parameter "csrfmiddlewaretoken". I only saw it because I started logging CSRF mismatch errors. I use Django and its injection safe MYSQL, but it's no fun to see this. Presumably, they're also trying with other parameters. For example, maybe they're putting it as the user login or password; values I don't log.

Answer (score 8):

This is a vulnerability check. It's one of the easiest and safest way to figure out if your server is vulnerable to SQL injection - and more importantly, it doesn't need any attention from the would-be attacker! You can use a method like this to test sites automatically for SQL injection vulnerabilities - and in this case, it means that the potential attacker can run any kind of query or command, you seem to have no checks whatsoever. Needless to say, this is bad.

You should consider your server compromised - it's probably on someone's list now, pending further exploitation. Fix the issue ASAP, and ideally prevent the functionality altogether right away if the real fix is going to take some time.

The idea behind this is that a vulnerable server will respond differently to a query with different values for the `sleep` argument - this means that it's very easy to automatically go through all possible inputs (don't forget that even things like hidden fields and dropdowns can be changed at will) and find out if any of those are vulnerable. When this works, you can either inject a malicious query/command outright, or keep using the `sleep` to figure out information directly - particularly useful when there's no data you could make appear to the outside by modifying the vulnerable query. By series of yes-no questions (based on simple `if(whatever, sleep(5), 0)`) you can determine enough to press your attack further.